# R: Plotting one set of beta coefficients

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, regression

I'm trying to plot just a set of beta coefficients in a **beta solution path plot** with R. Here are the beta values that I'm trying to plot:

```
                    s0
AtBat      .          
Hits       1.136258490
HmRun      .          
Runs       .          
RBI        .          
Walks      1.182645827
Years      .          
CAtBat     .          
CHits      .          
CHmRun     .          
CRuns      0.110122200
CRBI       0.314564189
CWalks     .          
LeagueN    .          
DivisionW  .          
PutOuts    0.003304879
Assists    .          
Errors     .          
NewLeagueN .
```

The type of plot that I want to get from this set of betas is:

[image]

And here is the code with which I'm trying to plot the betas:

```
tmp <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(beta))
tmp$coef <- row.names(tmp)
tmp <- reshape::melt(tmp, id = "coef")
tmp$norm <- apply(abs(beta[-1,]), 2, sum)[tmp$variable+1] # compute L1 norm
```

When I run the code above I get an error from `tmp$norm`: **Error in apply(abs(beta[-1, ]), 2, sum) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length**

Then I want to plot the betas with the code below which I cannot run because I don't get a `tmp$norm` value:

```
ggplot(tmp[tmp$coef != "(Intercept)",], aes(norm, value, color = coef, linetype = coef)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  xlab("L1 norm") + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = ""), 
         linetype = guide_legend(title = "")) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(3,"lines"))
```

Here is a simple beta reproducible code, to get some values of beta:

```
beta=matrix(sample(1:19),19,1)
```

The number of samples and predictors can be any arbitrary number, like number of samples n=200 and predictors =19.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I added some code with which betas can be reproduced, the main idea in my question is not to get a desired input or output, I just want to know how to plot a matrix(beta 19x1) like in the image in the question.